# defining a button as a link to a new page in extjs

Tags: extjs4

`enter code here`var text ='Fill' ;
    if(value != undefined && value !=''){
    text = Ext.Date.format(value,'Y-m-d');
}
    return ' '+text+' '

this above code is link to a new page when clicking 'Fill' link . i need that 'Fill' link to be as a button. How do i define a button instead of a text as a link using extjs

Answer (score 0):

The code is simple with JavaScript:

```
var btnLink = new Ext.Button({
  text: 'Fill',
  handler: function(){
    //you can put here any controls
    window.open("http://your-link-here.com", "_self")
  }
});
```

This will act as href opening link on the same page, and if you want to open it on a new window you can try window.open(url) instead..

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of LinkButton for ExtJS. It can be used as a link directly (set 'stopEvent' to false) or as a button (use subscription to 'click' event)

[LinkButton for ExtJs](https://gist.github.com/Pencroff/6868891)